# Swift Realm Database Storage + URL AND the Register/ Login functionality

Tags: database, swift, authentication, realm

I understand Realm is a Database Storage like CoreData. But I'm quite lost. After going through the documentation, I can't locate the tutorial for creating a login/register access to build for users. For instance, on Firebase, it gives you the tutorials for that, then provides you URL and other bits. Would I have to connect Realm with a cloud storage (like CloudKit) if I didn't want the database to exist on my computer?

I would plead for some sample codes to help me understand as I really want to use Realm.

I'm intent on building a social networking / messaging app.

Answer (score 1):

Realm is a mobile database which persists data locally.

> Would I have to connect Realm with a cloud storage […] if i didn't want the database to exist on my computer?"

So what you're asking for concretely is not exactly possible: the database will exist on the computer / mobile device all the time.

Beyond that you're responsible yourself for synchronizing your persistency layer with a backend service of your own choice. Realm doesn't offer yet any builtin mechanism for that.

On the [addons](https://realm.io/addons/) page of our website, you will find in the section Connectors some components, which might help you with using a backend service.

Comment: I appreciate that and am fully aware of my responsibility to that matter. However, I'm only asking for help as I believe most enterprises and business that have used realm use some cloud backend services. Especially startups.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a little more info, but your concern is very broad. I hope this helps you a little bit further.